# MySQL: select when count = sum & group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select user_id & quiz_id, for users which their count of questions in their quiz = sum of correct, this mean they answer 100% correct

answers table:

```
quiz_id      question_id      user_id      answer_id      correct
1                1               1             1            1
1                2               1             6            0
1                3               1             9            1
2                1               2             1            1
2                2               2             5            1
3                4               1            17            1
3                5               1            21            1
3                6               1            25            1
4                1               3             1            1
5                4               4            18            0
6                1               5             1            1
6                2               5             5            1
7                1               3             2            0
7                2               3             7            0
```

ex 1: 
user 1 took "quiz_id" = 1

count of questions in "quiz_id = 1" = 3

sum of correct = 2

so it's not 100%

user_id = 1 in quiz_id = 1 => will not selected

but user_id = 1 will be selected with quiz_id = 3 cause he got 100%

expected results:

```
quiz_id     user_id
  2            2
  3            1
  4            3
  6            5
```

notes:

1. quiz could be taken with different users with different number of
   questions
2. quiz_id, user_id unique together (user can not take same quiz twice)

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an aggregate query with `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT quiz_id, user_id
FROM quiz_answer -- or whatever the name is
GROUP BY quiz_id, user_id
HAVING COUNT(question_id) = SUM(correct)
```

here you must use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` because

> The HAVING clause can refer to aggregate functions, which the WHERE
>   clause cannot

as specified in [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html).